# Flutter navigator hides (covers) first window conent

Tags: flutter, view, routes, navigator

Why when I use the navigator to go to another page(widget) that covers just part of the screen, I can't see the first-page content (which is on top of the page)?

[image]

[image]

I tried code from this example (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) and modified it a little to show what I need:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding:const EdgeInsets.only(top:128),
      color:Colors.transparent,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Second Route'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Go back!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is expected. You are pushing a new screen (widget) on top of another. And since you've adding padding, the bottom white blank section is expected. Do you want to make the part of the first screen visible?

Comment: Yes, excatly, want to navigate, but keep part of first screen visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `bottom sheet`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'example',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void _show(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        elevation: 10,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: ctx,
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
              //change height to change height of bottom sheet
              height: MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height * 0.75,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('bottom sheet'),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Show The BottomSheet'),
            onPressed: () => _show(context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use this class instead of your class

```
    class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Route'),
      ),
      body: Container(
      padding:const EdgeInsets.only(top:128),
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Go back!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```